# Android: How set the direction of a vehicle in Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, tracking

I am developing an Android application where a bus is monitored by GPS. The position of the vehicle and the route to be traveled is displayed on Google Maps. On this route, the bus stops are also displayed.

Clicking on a bus stop, the system displays the estimated time of arrival of the bus to the bus stop.

The problem is: how do I check (or how can I know) if the bus has passed the bus stop selected, ie, how can I know that the bus stop is no longer part of the route, in the sense that the bus is traveling ?

Note: for now the system is a prototype, working WITH JUST 1 (ONE) BUS!

I hope you can give me some ideas!

Comment: how are you getting estimated time of arrival? it seems like you could use that to figure out if the bus has already passed a stop because the time to arrive at that location would no longer be valid.